# Contains method in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose we have the following code:

```
int item1=5;
int item2=6;
int item3=7;
int item4=5;

List<int> items= new List<int> {item1,item2,item3};

bool result= items.Contains(item4);
```

Now, the variable result should be:

a)false, because there is not a variable "item4" in the list.

b)true, because the value of item4 which is 5, is among the values of the items in the list.

What is the correct answer and why?
Could you please explain how the method Contains uses the Equals method?

Comment: Should be true. Int is a value type, so when you initialize the list it contains the values { 5, 6, 7}. Then Contains will use the default int comparison and find 5.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,521b9f7129105e15

Comment: The correct answer can be determined by just running the code.  What's happening here isn't specific to `Contains()`; you could do `item1 == item4` or `item1.Equals(item4)` as well, both of which are `true`.

Comment: `items` contains values, not variables.

Answer (score 3):

b. It doesn't matter if you write `item1`, `item4`, `5` or `10/2`; they all evaluate to the number five.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: B.

Long answer:

What List.Contains does is that it checks whether or not a list contains a value, e.g an int, bool or any other object. If you are wondering about the Equals method, well, the Equals method checks if two objects are the same value-wise.

This means that the code for Contains is most likely just

```cs
public void bool Contains(T value){
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; i++){
        if(self[i].Equals(value)) // Could prob be something else, and might use "==" instead of equals
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Close, but not exactly.

Comment: In what fashion?
Edit: oh, you mean i forgot to say b)?

Comment: "If you are wondering about the Equals method, well, the Equals method checks if two objects are the same value-wise." - is almost completely wrong. Definitely bad idea to post as "please explain how the method Contains uses the Equals method"...

Comment: Actually [`List.Contains`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L312) just defers to `Array.IndexOf` which kinda does what you say.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh is that so? I double checked on the wiki page and understood that as the answer, must have been wrong tho?

Comment: No idea what is "the wiki page" you've used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0 does not say anything about "same value-wise".

Comment: The rectangle example states so. new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200).Equals(new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200)) -> true, so then it must compare values since those are 2 different instances of the Rectangle class.